# Find the View in Eclipse which uses the onClick-Method

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have a `button` declared in XML, which uses `android:onClick="myOnClickMethod"`. In an Activity there's the implementation of `myOnClickMethod(View Button)`.

Now i would like to know if `Eclipse` supports a function, which finds and shows the `View` in the  `layout` that is using `myOnClickMethod(View Button)` or vice versa.

Same case for IDs of an `layout`/`view`.

This could save some time searching the right `view` / `method`.

I think its not possible anyway, but i give it a try.

Comment: put cursor on the method -> press `Ctrl/Cmd+H` -> 'File search' tab -> put `*.xml` as filename pattern -> press 'Search'

Comment: Go to search menu-File Search. Type whatever you want to serach in 'Containing text'. Select scope to 'Workspace'. Hit Search. Then you will find your search result

Answer (score -1):

No. Eclipse have not such feature. Only in layout designer properties panel, you can see onClick property of View.